# Getting all files with .lnk extension from certain path and open them with their names

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, wpf-controls

I want to get all .lnk files paths from Start Menu to array and open them with their names. I wrote something like that but it doesn't work at all. Any ideas?

```
string path = @"C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\";
string[] lnks = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.lnk");

foreach (var lnk in lnks)
{
    if (lnk.Contains(bgData[1]))
    { 
        Process.Start(lnk); 
        Hide();
        break; 

    }
}
```

Code triggers with first string from a textbox then need second string to get name of .lnk file.

Comment: Can you be a bit more clear about what is not working?  What exactly is happening compared with what you want to see?  Using `Directory.GetFiles()` as you do will also not search sub-directories unless you add a third parameter of `System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories` and use it like so: `string[] lnks = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.lnk", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);`

Comment: Well, it worked when I add `System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories` but now I'm getting an error: `An unhandled exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in mscorlib.dll` Can't access to Start Menu\Programs

Comment: The user that is running the application needs access to the files you are trying to access.  Make sure that file read permissions are set appropriately.